# Map concurrency - modification exception

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

The below code is executed by a thread pool. First, the Map was not concurrent so I have changed that but I still get modification exception on the second line.
What changes should I make in order to turn this piece of code to be thread safe?

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Account> entriesOnFile = IniReaderHelper.load();
for (Map.Entry<String,Account> entryFromFile: entriesOnFile.entrySet())
{
    EntryWrapper wrapperFromEntriesFile = new EntryWrapper(entryFromFile.getValue());
    if (wrapperFromEntriesFile.getName().equals(entryName))
    {
        Tracer.info("Found matching entry from the entries file for +'" + entryName + "'");
        synchronized(this) 
        {
            context.put(RequestServices.ENTRY_WRAPPER, wrapperFromEntriesFile);
        }
        entry = wrapperFromEntriesFile;
        break;
    }               
}
```

Some more information:
Below is the code for the .load() function that returns the map:

```
static public ConcurrentHashMap<String, Account> load() throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    accounts.clear();
    try
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getEntriesFile()));
        Account current = null;
        String accountName;
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
                ... do stuff here then adding entry to the amp
                accounts.put(accountName, current);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
    return accounts;
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
error code [1] : java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at .....call(AsyncCommand.java:78)
```

The stack trace points to the 2nd line (the 'for' loop) and it writes "EntryIterator.next" so doesn't this mean that I should change:

```
for (Map.Entry<String,Account> entryFromFile: entriesOnFile.entrySet())
```

to

```
for (ConcurrentHashMap.Entry<String,Account> entryFromFile: entriesOnFile.entrySet())
```

Here is the decleration for 'accounts'

```
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Account> accounts = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Account>();
```

Comment: It does not look like you are modifying the entriesOnFile Map so there is either code you are not showing us or you are not telling us what your exception actually is.

Comment: I'm not trying to modify the map. I read some entries of type Account from a file into entriesOnFile. Then I go over each entry in the map and compare its name to entryName and if its a match I do some stuff. The exception that I get is modify and its on the 2nd line, where the "for" is. I got the logs from one of my customers, I couldn't actually recreate this in lab since this entire part of code is running at extreme circumstances.

Comment: You should post the stack trace! It sounds like there is something else going on because if you are not modifying the map then there is no reason you should be getting a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. It's not modified after loaded (in line 1), but the loading itself is modification I guess. This entire code is executed in a thread pool so the same map is used by different threads. This is why I changed map to concurrent map in line 1. here is the stack:

error code [1] : java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

 at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)

 at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)

Obviously, according to the stack, the problem is with the iterator, how can I "tread safe" it?

Comment: Your stack trace implies you are still working with a HashMap and not a ConcurrentHashMap. If you refer to the api definition for entry set "The view's iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw ConcurrentModificationException, and guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, and may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.". Thus if you are actually using a concurrent hash map it should not be possible to have this exception thrown while iterating over the map.

Comment: You should also post a bit more context around the code. Currently it is impossible to tell where the Map is coming from and how exactly it is shared between threads.

Comment: The map is created on the first line, actually returned from the load function so there is nothing else relevant in the code.
However, I found in a different thread the following statement:
"Iterators returned by ConcurrentHashMap.iterator() will return each element once at most and will not ever throw ConcurrentModificationException"

So maybe all I should do is change
for (Map.Entry<String,Account> entryFromFile: entriesOnFile.entrySet())

To:
for (ConcurrentHashMap.Entry<String,Account> entryFromFile: entriesOnFile.entrySet())

Comment: If this bit of code is run within a method (that is invoked by multiple threads concurrently), and the first line really creates a new method-local Map (rather than returning a reference to a shared one), then there is no way for those threads to be working on the same Map concurrently. Hence I suspect the IniReaderHelper.load() actually returns a shared Map instance. But without any context around the bit of code you posted, I can't really say for sure.

Comment: Post the declaration of `accounts`. The stacktrace indicates it's a `HashMap`, not a `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: I have updated my post with 'accounts' decleration

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, sharing the accounts map across threads makes no sense (you are clearing and rebuilding the map on every call to load(), so the most straightforward fix is to remove the shared static Map (accounts) and have load() create and return a new Map on each call.

Comment: but the intention of "load" may be more like "refresh" for a singleton, in which case that aspect of the design may be OK

Comment: This code runs only when something goes wrong and we need to build the map again, this is why it's static, usually this code is not read.

Comment: You might want to encapsulate the Map and its loading a bit more in a class, and apply concurrency control to the reloading to ensure threads dont step on each others toes. You can do this by using the synchronized keyword or an explicit Lock and possibly a timestamp to indicate when the map was last reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me from what you've said thus far that the map is shared at all. You could synchronize access to the load method and copy the contents of the map before letting another thread mutate the accounts field. Another option is to change the load method to accept a map it can populate rather than having it mutate a shared one.

Having said that, the exception does not make sense. CHM does not return a HashMap$EntryIterator, it returns a ConcurrentHashMap$EntryIterator and there's no way for that to throw the stack you describe here. My guess is that you are not running the code you posted but an older version by mistake. Try running in a debugger, or add a log statement to verify the posted code is actually run.

Comment: Couldn't it because of this:
    for (Map.Entry<String,Account> entryFromFile: entriesOnFile.entrySet())

Shouldn't I use ConcurrentHashMap.Entry instead of Map.entry?
This exception is not happening in my lab, it happens on a customer's so I can't really test anything.
I'm starting to believe that customer is using wrong version of my code, before I moved the Map to concurrent.

Comment: That's basically what I'm saying... look at CHM code, it could not produce the stacktrace you present -> this is not the code being run